# Mongoose Could not find path "${filterPath}" in schema by updating a subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In this **Items** object:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "_id": "63a48f12a9731cfd8a64b0b1",
            "item_name": "addidas shoes",
            "__v": 0,
            "rating": [
                {
                    "_id": "63a48fd51fb70775d216eb87",
                    "rate": 1,
                    "user_id": "6398a1a157d6146413b23b43"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to update the `rating` property if a `user_id` inside of it already exists, else, add a new object into it.

```
  const addRating = async (req, res) => {
  const { rate, user_id, item_id } = req.body;
  // item_id = 63a48f12a9731cfd8a64b0b1 user_id = 6398a1a157d6146413b23b43 rate = 6

  // Adding ratings to the selected item
  const test = await itemDB.item.updateOne(
    { _id: item_id, rating: { user_id: user_id } },
    { $push: { "items.rating.$[i].rate": rate } },
    { arrayFilters: [{ "i.user_id": user_id }], upsert: true }
  );
  console.log(test);
  res.json({ message: "success" });
};
```

I wanted to change something in the rating property so I set the filter as above but it gives me this error when hitting the endpoint:

```
\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\update\castArrayFilters.js:74
        throw new Error(`Could not find path "${filterPath}" in schema`);
              ^

Error: Could not find path "items.rating.0.user_id" in schema
```

This is my **Items Schema:**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const RateSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  rate: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  user_id: {
    type: mongoose.ObjectId,
  },
  item_id: {
    type: mongoose.ObjectId,
  },
});

const ItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  item_name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  rating: {
    type: [RateSchema],
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Items", ItemSchema);
```

Comment: What is at line 74 of castArrayFilters.js?

Comment: @Joe [line 74](https://imgur.com/a/x2E2YtB) it's the thrown error message.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is not noticing that `items` is also an array when applying the array filter to `rating`.

Try using the all-positional operator like:

```
 { $push: { "items.$[].rating.$[i].rate": rate } }
```

Comment: It's giving me the same error   `throw new Error(Could not find path "${filterPath}" in schema);
              ^

Error: Could not find path "items.0.rating.0.user_id" in schema`


I made sure that my user_id is not empty. I'm not sure why this doesn't get located.

Comment: Oh, I misread your schema.

Comment: Since the RateSchema is referenced in the ItemSchema, Mongoose is apparently not able to validate the array filter.  Try moving the field definitions to the ItemSchema.

Comment: Okay, I directly moved it to the ItemSchema like so
 `rating: {
    type: mongoose.Schema({
      rate: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
      },
      user_id: {
        type: mongoose.ObjectId,
      },
      item_id: {
        type: mongoose.ObjectId,
      },
    }),`

but it's giving me the same error. Guess I'll just change my schema and give the rating property an id of the rating schema instead to be used as a reference then use aggregate pipeline when fetching the two.